# Add class to wrapping element

Tags: jquery

I'm using the script below to add an active stage according to the current page url.

At the moment, it is adding the "active" class to the `<a>` tag.
How can I add the class to the wrapping `<li>` element instead?

```js
$(function() {
  var currenturl = window.location.href;
  $("#navigation ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == currenturl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

I think I could use `.wrap()` somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: are you actually putting the entire url in the href of the a tag?

Comment: no, relative links. But in browser they are seen as absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.parent` if it is the direct parent you want to add the class or `.closest` if it is even higher (parent's parent and so on).

```
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
```

Assuming it is direct parent from the selector `#navigation ul li a`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

this works if the `a` tag is somewhere inside the `li` tag (does not necessarily have to be the direct child)

Comment: in this is case, it is the direct child but another great solution